# How to fetch all records from 2 tables

Tags: django

I have 2 models

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)


class UserRole(models.Model):

    employee_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, to_field='employee_id', unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supervisor_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
```

and have defined seriallizers for both models

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = models.CustomUser


class UserRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
         fields = '__all__'
         model = models.UserRole
```

consider i have 5 records in both tables

How to fetch all records from both tables (email, employee_id, supervisor_id )
like,  where CustomUser.employee_id = UserRole.employee_id

I tried with

```
models.CustomUser.objects.select_related('UserRole')
```

But, not able to fetch records from UserRole table.

UserRole.objects.select_related('employee_id')
 -- this is fetching only userRole records
Thanks in Advance

Comment: "Also, how to serialize the data of 2 serializers to create one object which holds all fields." Please post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I think from  `UserRole` you want to all information about `employe`'s too. What i am thinking you want to get all details information of `employee_id` foreign_key relation. This can be done by

```
 UserRole.objects.all()
```

with the following serializers.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('email','employee_id',)
        model = models.CustomUser


class UserRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employee_id = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
         fields = ('employee_id','supervisor_id',)
         model = models.UserRole
```

Comment: I got only UserRole object. it doesn't have CustomUser fields.

Comment: can you add this response in comment or post.

Comment: @sheik i have updated my answer. Am i thinking your need right ?

Comment: I need both employee details and userrole details.. something like, select e*, u* from employee e, userrole u where e.employee_id=u.employee_id

Comment: in UserRole table there is employee_id , which is in relation with `custom_user` model, right. then this should do the work for you.

Comment: @sheik after serliazer the query_data with `UserRoleSerializer` ? may sound stupid but make sure you pass your query_set to serializer, then please tell.

Comment: serializer = UserRoleSerializer(models.UserRole.objects.all(), many=True)
print(serializer.data) .. 

i got below error

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `password` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'password'.


password is one of additional field in CustomUser model

Comment: @sheik fields = '__all__' have some evil side effect too. Sometimes in response we may get unexpected field value. So instead of using '__all__' please add necessary fields that you think is important. Also in djnago password store as a crypted_value, retriving that causing the problem i am guessing. I have updated the response a bit. kindly please check, thank you for your response.

Comment: got below error


AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `email` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `str` instance.
Original exception text was: 'str' object has no attribute 'email'.

Comment: no luck.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `email` is not valid for model `UserRole`.

Comment: @sheik i do have a hackish solution but not sure this should be appropriate or not. If you wish i can edit. But nevertheless i think i have lack of knowledge to figure out your problem. I am sorry for that. Hope someone will figure out this.

Comment: I tried with below. I got values from both tables

results = models.CustomUser.objects.all().values('id', 'name', 'email', 'contact_number', 'userrole__supervisor_id')

Answer (score 0):

You don't get automatic joins in Django, no need for it because you can just follow the ForeignKey relation on the object (`the_object_you_get.its_foreign_key`). Now, of course, that will hit the DB twice. if you'd rather avoid that, you can use something like `.prefetch_related('employee_id')` on whatever queryset you need to use. This will prevent you from hitting the DB multiple times (at the price of one larger initial query of course).

Finally, if you wanna serialize a ForeignKey relation, the answer Shakil gave is pretty comprehensive. Only thing is that you don't necessarily need to set the `employee_id` field as `read_only=True` (a bit of a limitation). You can also override the `UserRoleSerializer` `.create()` the method so that it calls the `.create()` method of `UserSerializer`.